# Central page for error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

In my ASP.NET C# application, there are many different error messages that I'd like to display.

The way I display my error message is by pop by via:

```
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('My error message here');", true);
        return;
```

Since there are many different error messages (some repeated across pages) and I have so many different pages in my application - I'd like to put all the error message on a centralized page and reference to it somehow - so that when I need to change my error message, I only need to change in one page and not across ALL the pages.

What's the best way to do this?

I imagine I need to create a .cs page? And have a different ID for each of the error messages.

This seems like a very simple thing to do but I am a bit lost as to how to start on it.

Can someone advice the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you probably want to write the errors to a database then just have a reporting page that show them all in a grid or something.

Comment: Seem you need ELMAH log library, it has a page to view all error in your web app

Comment: Elmah is unhandled exception logging. It sounds like he wants to notify users of things, such as validation failure. And he wants a central place to manage the text of these. Elmah doesn't do that that I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would add extension method to show the alerts and keep all the exception strings in resource file. then I can call the method as below

**USAGE**

```
this.ShowAlert(Resource1.MyException);
```

**EXTENSION METHOD**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void ShowAlert(this Control control, string message)
        {
            if (!control.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("msgbox"))
            {
                var script = String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
                control.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(control.Page.GetType(), "msgbox", script, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add resource file to your project and enter messages as string entries with meaning full names.

Comment: Thanks Damith - I have now created a resource page errormsg.resx. I have an entry in there with name: error1, and value: my test error message. How do I call on this page in my .cs file to display error1's value?

Comment: My only problem now is that I don't know how to call on the Resource1 page. My page does not recognise it when I reference my Resource page. Any ideas?

Comment: Add resource page to your asp.net project and after you add item to it VS will generate property to access it. go to errormsg.Designer.cs file and you can find the property and class name.

Comment: @viv_acious You need to call this Extension method from your ASPX page code behind not in class library or other `cs` class

Comment: Thanks - I managed to access by typing: this.ShowAlert((string)GetGlobalResourceObject("ErrorMessages", "error1")); instead.

THanks so much for your help: A final question: I got it working now, but when the error message comes up (pops up), but the whole background turns grey now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to display JavaScript error messages I would create a JS include file and define the JS methods there. That way you can reuse the methods on all pages that include the JS file.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-javascript-file-using-script-tag

Comment: Thanks TGH! So, I create a new *.js page, and add things like var errorMs1 = "error message 1", then include it in my aspx.cs page? How do I call on errorMs1 from the aspx.cs page? (Apologies, I'm a newbie with js!)

Comment: Try something like this:http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/execute-javascript-function-from-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

JS method can be defined in 

 * the Master Page

 * in the  custom base class inherited by all the pages.